# Firebase won't show me Crashlytics details without linking Fabric app

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I set up a new project with Firebase and enabled Crashlytics crash reporting. My Firebase console is showing crashes (so I know the SDK is configured properly):

[image]

However, when I click on the crashes, I'm presented with this dialog:

[image]

Ok...but this app doesn't exist in Fabric, nor do I have a Fabric account (actually - I did have a Fabric account, but deleted it). AND if I create a new Fabric account, there is nowhere to "add" an app anyway. **What am I missing?**

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Can you double check that you've selected the right app in the project you're in? It's possible that when changing Firebase projects, a different app was selected.

Comment: Hi Mike - in this particular account I only have the one Firebase project. My current theory is that I had an old (unused) Fabric account under the same email address I use for Google/Firebase - and there is an issue with Firebase still thinking I have a Fabric account? I deleted said account when I started having these issues, but that hasn't changed any behavior on the Firebase side.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Firebase app is connected successfully before trying Crashlatics.

Complete the steps of adding Firebase, probably you were forcing the crash which disabled the Firebase from connecting to the console.